# "error": { "code": 400, "message": "RecognitionAudio not set.", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } }

Tags: java, json

I want to send request http POST to **Cloud Speech API** with editor **Cloud Shell**    through this command →

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @request.json \
"https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=AIzaSyBZMZwv1-WLSMG-OBJiaDQ6Q9oYEff5vEo"
```

I am following the official tutorial https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-speech-intro/index.html?index=..%2F..index#2, but when I run the command in the editor, the response is this →

```
 {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "RecognitionAudio not set.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

The code that I wrote in "**request.json**" file is this one →

```
{
  "config": {
      "encoding":"FLAC",
      "languageCode": "en-US",
  },
  "audio": {
      "uri":"gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the error you mention when there is no `request.json` file in the folder where I execute the curl command.

Comment: Check that you really have request.json in folder where you run curl command

Comment: Okey. Its resolved. I had to put this one--->                                                    
                                                                                                                   
  gcloud ml speech recognize 'gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac' \
   --language-code='en-US'